# Refit / HttpClient / ModernHttpClient - 400 Bad Request

Tags: c#, httpclient, reactiveui, reactive, refit

Recently started with ReactiveUI and so far so good. While trying to figure out stuff I came across a `HttpClient / Refit` problem. I have a long list and every item in that list have to make a request to a API as follows.

This is a ReactiveObject

```
public SearchResult()
{
    LoadStats = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(_ => DownloadMultipleCalls(this.IdText, this.DisplayText));

    LoadStats
        .ThrownExceptions
        .SubscribeOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .Subscribe(ex => UserError.Throw("Couldn't load stats", ex));

    _avaText = LoadStats.Select(x => x.Ava).ToProperty(this, x => x.AvaText, string.Empty);
    _perText = LoadStats.Select(x => x.Per).ToProperty(this, x => x.PerText, string.Empty);

    this.WhenAnyValue(x => x.IdText)
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
                //.Select(_ => Observable.Timer(DateTimeOffset.MinValue, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), RxApp.MainThreadScheduler))
        .Retry(5)
        .InvokeCommand(LoadStats);
}
```

In DownloadMultipleCalls the following is happening.

```
async static Task<AvaPer> DownloadMultipleCalls(string id, string displaytext)
{
    AvaPer response = new AvaPer();
    var block = new ActionBlock<string>(async service =>
    {
        response = await DownloadCall(service, displaytext);
    },
    new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4 });

    block.Post(id);

    block.Complete();
    await block.Completion;

    return response;
}

async static Task<AvaPer> DownloadCall(string id, string displaytext)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Starting download at {DateTimeOffset.Now}");

    var client = new HttpClient(NetCache.UserInitiated)
    {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.adres.com"),
    };

    //client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);

    var token = GetToken;

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("authToken", token);
    var api = RestService.For<IMyApi>(client);

    AvaPer idEntries = new AvaPer();
    try
    {
        var searchResult = await api.GetAvaPerStatusRaw(id); // <== Here is the error (400 - Bad Request)

        //var parsedEntries = Task.Run(() => {
        idEntries = new AvaPer
        {
            Id = searchResult.Id.ToString() ?? string.Empty,
            display = displaytext ?? string.Empty,
            Ava = searchResult.AvailabilityStatus ?? string.Empty,
            Per = searchResult.PerformanceStatus ?? string.Empty,
            Updated = DateTimeOffset.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString() ?? string.Empty
        };
        //}).ConfigureAwait(false);

        //return idEntries;
    }
    catch (ApiException ex)
    {
        var statusCode = ex.StatusCode;
        var error = ex.GetContentAs<Models.ServiceModel.ErrorResponse>();
    }

    return idEntries;
}
```

Finally it goes all wrong with this line of code `var searchResult = await api.GetAvaPerStatusRaw(id);` The app crashes with a response "400 Bad Request" and if I look into the error it sais that the there is no id value inplace of the GET request. But when I check the initial value of `id`  there is a value so it should not respond with that. Can anyone help me with this? If you have any question, please do not hesitate to ask. Thank you very much.

Kind regards,

Fernando

Comment: Not sure, other than getting a 400, what it goes south entails.  On the ModernHttpClient github page it shows the HttpClient init different though.  Like this ```var httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());```.

Comment: @phil Thank you for your answer. I have edited the post a bit, so hopefully it's clearly now. And you are correct about ModernHttpClient, I'm using Refit to do my POST, GET etc.. requests and Refit uses ModernHttpClient underneath it. Besides that I have tried this without Refit, but I will get the same results when I only use ModernHttpClient.

Comment: What does your interface look like?